# segmentation fault while trying to run graphics in yasm

Tags: assembly, x86-64, yasm

I'm trying to learn assembly for x86_64 and the only problem for now is with the VGA graphics. It tells me "Segmentation fault (core dumped)
".

the loop func is to freeze the code.

I've tried a lot of tutorials in the WEB, but none of them helped me.

```
mov ax, 0x0a000
mov es, ax
mov ah, 00H
mov al, 13H
int 10H

mov ah, 0ch
mov al, 03h
mov cx, 70
mov dx, 70
mov bh, 1
int 10h

jmp _loop
```

I expected to draw a pixel.

Answer (score 2):

That's not x86-64 assembly but 16-bit assembly code.
If you run this in a 64-bit OS I would expect a segmentation fault.

This code needs to be run in real mode, probably in DOS. Today this probably means to run this code in DOSBOX or a similar emulator, but is should be possible to boot a modern machine to DOS and run this code.

Comment: That code only uses `int 10h` BIOS calls; it would also work in a legacy BIOS bootloader that ran freestanding instead of under DOS.